# Memory issue implementing quick sort

Tags: c++, quicksort

I am trying to implement quick sort to sort a sequence of integers. 
I am getting a segmentation default with the following code:

I implemented partition and quick sort recursive calls.But for some c++ reason I am getting an access to memory or an infinite loop I cant understand why.

```
   #include <fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int pivotSelection(vector<int> A){
    return 0;
}

int partition(vector<int> &A,int l,int r){
    int i=l+1;
    int p = A[l];
    for(int j=0; j< A.size(); j++) {
        if(A[j]<p){
            swap(A[j], A[i] );
            i=i+1;
        }
    }
    swap(A[l], A[i-1]);
    return i;
}

vector<int> readArray(char* file){
    ifstream inFile;
    vector<int> A;
    inFile.open(file);
    int x;
    while (inFile >>x ) {
        A.push_back(x);
    }
    return A;
}

void quickSort(vector<int> &A, int l,int r){
    if(r==1) {
        return ;
    }
    if(r>l){
        int p= partition(A,l,r);
        quickSort(A,l,p-1);
        quickSort(A,p+1,r);
    }
}

int  main(){

vector<int> A;//= readArray((char*)"/home/brunoeducsantos/AlgorithmFoundation/quicksort/data.txt");

A.push_back(3);
A.push_back(5);
A.push_back(7);
A.push_back(1);
int length = A.size();

quickSort(A,0,length-1);

for(int i=0;i<length;i++) cout<<A[i]<<endl;
return 0;


};
```

The expected result is: 1 3 5 7

Comment: Why do you pass the vector *by value* to the `quickSort` function?

Comment: Also, please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: As a matter of style, this code is a somewhat confusing mix of array indexing and iterators. It would probably be clearer if you replaced the two calls to `tter_swap` with just plain `swap`: `std::swap(A[j], A[i]);` and `std::swap(A[0], A[i-1]);`.

Comment: I sorted out the issue with this new edit I show on the post. Thanks for your feedback.
But now for some reason is not changing the vector when I recursive call quickSort. Any hints?
Thanks

Comment: If the code in the question no longer have the problem you ask about, it makes the question itself totally worthless. Remember that this site isn't only your personal QA site, it's for everyone who might have this or a similar problem. If a comment or an answer helped you, then comment so, and perhaps add a paragraph explaining how you solved it (if the comment or answer didn't explain it fully).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixes noted in comments:

```
int partition(vector<int> &A,int l,int r){
    int i=l+1;
    int p = A[l];
    for(int j=i; j<=r; j++) {         // fix
        if(A[j]<p){
            swap(A[j], A[i] );
            i=i+1;
        }
    }
    swap(A[l], A[i-1]);
    return i-1;                         // fix
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction. It makes a lot of sense.